# In which states should I linearize the system? $\dot{x} =f(x,u)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, jacobian, linearization

Let's say that I have a nonlinear ODE-system on first order:

$$\dot{x} =f(x,u)$$

And I know when the system is static

$$0 = f(x_e, u_e)$$

But in what states should I linearize the system? Because the state vector $x_e$ contains position and zero velocity.

**Question:**

In which states should I linearize the system?
Can I linearize the system so the second order system becomes zero, e.g zero acceleration?

$$\ddot{x} = F(x, u)$$
$$0 = F(x_e, u_e)$$

Or in what states $x$ and input $u$ should I linearize in?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify *why* you want to linearise. You can linearise the system wherever you like (barring singularities), but it leads you nowhere. You don’t linearise for its own sake.

Comment: To have a linear system ofc. The problem is what velocity states should I use? I Know the states when the system is static. Ok...I even know the input when the system is static. But if i linearize when the system is static, I will lose the velocity of the system.

Comment: *To have a linear system ofc.* – Of course. But what do you want to do with that linear system? A linearisation isn’t an end in itself but only the foundation for further steps of analysis. Without knowing those steps, it’s impossible to say what is an appropriate realisation.

Comment: I'm going to build a model based control system. Another problem with my linearization is that I get an unstable system, because the nonlinear system is to complex. No, I haven't model wrong equations. It's a very basic ODE, but it contains $cos (x), sin (x), x^2$  and $\frac{1}{x^2*cos(x)}$etc. Can I linearize without jacobian matrix? Just linearize by using approximations? E.g insted of $sin (x)$ I use a scalar times $x$ ? I should have learn nonlinear control.

Comment: I using newtonian mechanics by the way.